# Firefox and Edge capabilities settings for deactivating images - WDIO

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio-v6

I want to run cross browsing testing instead of only one browser (Chrome) for configuring Chrome to run headless and deactivate images i use the following in `wdio.conf.js` file :

```
 browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: chrome_args,
            prefs: {
                "profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation": 2,
                "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2
            }
        },
```

what's the equivalent of that for firefox and Edge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent for *Firefox* is

```
browserName: 'firefox',
'moz:firefoxOptions': {
args: ['-headless'],
args: firefox_args,
prefs: {
"geo.enabled": false,
"permissions.default.image": 2
},
  "windowSize": "1024x768"
},
```

The equivalent for *Edge* is

```
browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
'ms:edgeOptions': {
args: ['-headless'],
args: edge_args,
prefs: {
"geolocation": 2,
"images": 2
},
  windowSize: "1280x1024"
},
```

Comment: thanks alot can you please add headless and windows size in prefs and that woul be all